# Polymer broken href for internal pages

Tags: javascript, html, routes, polymer

So, I'm using polymer starter kit, but something doesn't feels right.

I created a new 'page', but the url doesn't change when i access through the menu. Then, inside this page, there is a `<paper-button>` with a link `<a>` to another html file on the same folder, but it doesn't work, when you click it says "Cant find: https:www.mywholelink.com/. Redirecting to your home page"

On the index.html, i've added the item in the menu

```
<a data-route="mobile" href="{{baseUrl}}mobile">
        <iron-icon icon="settings-cell"></iron-icon>
        <span>Register your smartphone</span>
</a>
```

Then, on the same file, i have the 'page'

```
 <section data-route="mobile" tabindex="-1">
    <paper-material elevation="1">

            <a href="{{baseUrl}}device.html" tabindex="-1">
                <paper-button raised><iron-icon icon="favorite"></iron-icon>Add your phone</paper-button>
            </a>
            <p>Wanna contribute?</p>
            <p>By adding your phone you are becoming a sensor to this experiment</p>
            <p>Also, you can see the phone sensor data in real time through your browser</p>
            <p><b>All data is collected anonymously</b></p>

    </paper-material>
 </section>
```

I made sure to add code to the elements/routing.html

```
 page('/mobile', function() {
  app.route = 'mobile';
  setFocus(app.route);
});
```

I'm hours on this and I don't know what i'm missing, please help

Comment: `https:www.mywholelink.com` is not a valid URL; its a page-relative url that likely goes nowhere...

Comment: I used this link just as an example here...

Comment: for starter you are missing a dollar sign with href: href$="{{baseUrl}}mobile".